# Changing default behaviour of wifi icon - Android

Tags: android, networking, wifi, default, behavior

I have an app idea and have a simple question, can I change the behaviour of wifi item on quick settings menu on Android? I want it to redirect to my app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not generally.

You can examine Logcat and see what happens when the user taps that tile. *If* the tile starts an activity (probably yes) and the `Intent` that is used is implicit (action but no `ComponentName` or package), then you could create an activity with a matching `<intent-filter>`. The user would be able to choose to launch your activity instead of the standard one.

However, bear in mind that there is no requirement that the `Intent` that the tile uses would be the same across Android versions and device manufacturers.

Comment: I'm 99.9% positive it explicitly launches built-in settings package. Intercepting clicks on quick settings would be considered a malicious behavior in most cases, so there's little to no reason to let people do that.

Comment: @Pawel: "I'm 99.9% positive it explicitly launches built-in settings package" -- that would not surprise me at all.